# Why does the Total scope increase shows negative value in Sprint burndown chart of Azure Devops?

Tags: azure, sprint

I am seeing negative values Under the "Total Scope increase" even though -
1.all the tasks were added on the first day of the sprint
2.No additional scope was added .

Can u let me know on what basis Azure devops calculates the Total scope increase and what are the possible conditions that the value for "Total scope increase " can go negative